# input and my array are baffling me

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

To save time, and what something I must be clearly passing over I am going to post my whole code. This is a console application I was sending a friend who is starting off in C#...

The problem is, when I enter exit from the get go, it exits. But, lets say I hit enter. Then I hit A for an array. Hit 5, or 6 or whatever number. Gives me the array. Lets say I want to sort it. It sorts. But, if I hit EXIT it says no match. I do not understand this. What is going on???

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication405
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate the delegate.
        Del handler = DelegateMethod;
        string _a = "";
        constructor con = new constructor();
        bool control = true;
        while (control)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter EXIT to end the program.");
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter for options");
            ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key.Equals(ConsoleKey.Enter))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter C for a constructor.");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter M for a method.");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter A for an array.");
                Console.WriteLine("Enter D for a delegate.");
            }
            _a = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (_a.ToUpper())
            {
                case "EXIT":
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program.");
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "C":
                    Console.WriteLine(con.a);
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to test another scenario?");
                    _a = Console.ReadLine(); 
                    if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                    {
                        continue; 
                    }
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    metroid();
                    break;
                case "A":
                    Array();
                    break;
                case "D":
                    // call the delegate
                    handler("This is how you call a delegate. Also, Pasta noodles taste like wontons!!! =)");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("No match");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    public delegate void Del(string message);
    public static void DelegateMethod(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }
    public class constructor
    {
        public string a = "This a is a constructor!";
    }
    static public void metroid()
    {
        string b = "This is a method!";
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
    static public void Array()
    {
        int temp, k;
        string ssSize = "";
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is a random array. Please enter the size.");
            string sSize = Console.ReadLine();
            int arraySize = Convert.ToInt32(sSize);
            int[] size = new int[arraySize];
            Random rd = new Random();
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
            {
                size[i] = rd.Next(arraySize);
                Console.WriteLine(size[i].ToString());
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Would you like to sort this array?");
            ssSize = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ssSize.ToUpper() == "Y")
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < size.Length; i++)
                {
                    temp = size[i];
                    k = i - 1;
                    while (k >= 0 && size[k] > temp)
                    {
                        size[k + 1] = size[k];
                        k--;
                    }
                    size[k + 1] = temp;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("\nThe sorted array is as follows: ");
                for (int i = 0; i < size.Length; i++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(size[i]);

                }
                Console.WriteLine("Note that this uses an insertion sort.");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fine! Don't sort it --  your loss!!!");
            }
        }
        catch (System.FormatException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not correct format, restarting array process.");
            Array();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when you enter `EXIT` after displaying the first prompt, you use `Console.ReadKey()` to read the first character. So the value in `_a` variable doesn't have `e` and is only `xit`.

Move displaying options to be at the same level as the rest and the problem will go away:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Instantiate the delegate.
        Del handler = DelegateMethod;
        string _a = "";
        constructor con = new constructor();
        bool control = true;
        while (control)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter EXIT to end the program.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter O for options");
            _a = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (_a.ToUpper())
            {
                case "EXIT":
                    Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using AJ's program.");
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "O":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter C for a constructor.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter M for a method.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter A for an array.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter D for a delegate.");
                    break;
                case "C":
                    Console.WriteLine(con.a);
                    Console.WriteLine("Would you like to test another scenario?");
                    _a = Console.ReadLine();
                    if (_a.ToUpper() == "Y")
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    control = false;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    metroid();
                    break;
                case "A":
                    Array();
                    break;
                case "D":
                    // call the delegate
                    handler("This is how you call a delegate. Also, Pasta noodles taste like wontons!!! =)");
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("No match");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know what I was thinking last night. I only have a few beers but I still should have recognized this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
```

And it's eating the first character of the line because you didn't hit ENTER before writing the command.

The best solution will be to replace `ENTER` with the text `"HELP"` and then stick to `Console.Readline`.

Example:

```
        while (control)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter EXIT to end the program, HELP for options");
            _a = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (_a.ToUpper())
            {
                case "HELP":
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter C for a constructor.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter M for a method.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter A for an array.");
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter D for a delegate.");
                    break;
                case "EXIT":
                ....
                ...
```